# Access JavaScript object elements by index

Tags: javascript

In the following code I want to access key, value dynamically in the for loop. How can I do it?

```
 s= {5: "456", 6: "123"} 
 var count = Object.keys(s).length
 for (var j_cnt=0;j_cnt<count;j_cnt++)
 {

 }
```

Note: `I do not want a normal for loop since i need to something with the count`

Comment: Why not use a `for in` loop?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: key/value pairs in JSON objects are specifically unordered. Use `for in` loop to access

Comment: I  do not want a normal for loop since i need to something with the count

Comment: Could you clarify what "count" you're talking about and what it has to do with using or not using a for loop?

Comment: I am referring to count because i need to add elements dynamically which can be done only in this loop

Comment: Please show a larger context. It's almost certain that you can do whatever you want to do with a for..in loop as well.

Comment: You want to add elements to the object in a for loop that you want to use to list its key/value pairs? I don't understand ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the count, define an external `count` variable and increment inside your `for in` loop:

```
var s     = {5: "456", 6: "123"},
    count = 0;

for (var key in s) {
    if (s.hasOwnProperty(key))
        console.log(s[key]);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: @Hulk -- What is the difference doing it your way or this? Both give the current index and both are set to stop at the Object keys' length.

Answer (score 1):

This is not "best practice", but as you are specifically looking for the for loop ...

```
s= {5: "456", 6: "123"} 
var count = Object.keys(s).length;
for (var j_cnt=0; j_cnt<count; j_cnt++) {
   var theKey = Object.keys(s)[j_cnt];
   var theValue = s[theKey];
}
```